# C# confusing method

Tags: c#, arrays, testing

I've been struggling to understand what's going on with a method I've got to understand for my test, I'm having a hard time figuring out the reason I'm getting the results I get, any explanation on how the "f" method works it's greatly appreciated

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    A b = new A(); b.y = b.x;
    b.f(b.y); b.g();
    Console.WriteLine(b.x[0] + " " + b.x[1]); // Prints 1 7
    Console.WriteLine(b.y[0] + " " + (b.x[1] + b.y[1])); // 1 14
  }
}

public class A {
  public int[] x = {1, 2};
  public int[] y;
  public void f(int[] z)
  {
      z[1] += 5;
  }

  public void g()
  {
      A a = new A ();
      a.x[0]++;
      a.x[1]--;
  }
}
```

Let me explain what I did understand, b.y gets created as an array and it gets the values in b.x, now, when we call b.f, we pass that method b.y which is [1, 2], now, and here's where I get stuck, z seems to be the b.y array, so it has [1, 2] as value, when the method adds 5 to the element in the position 1 (which is 2) I get [1, 7] as result of that, when the method ends and my program goes back to the main, somehow, b.y AND b.x BOTH are now [1, 7], how did that happen?, I thought the method was only modifying b.y since that's the one that got passed. Also, the g function doesn't add anything as the "a" value is a local variable that "dies" as the method ends, right?. I hope someone can help me, I've got to pass this test!. Thanks ;]

Comment: Wow. This is on your test? I hope your tutor never gets into our industry with naming standards like that..

Comment: Haha, that's 15 points item for the test, it's only an introduction to c# class, nothing advanced!.

Comment: I can't thank you both enough, Simon's answer was easier to understand or, at least, more detailed. I'm reading what you sent me Konstantin, again, thank you both for your time!.

Comment: The naming standards are only the tip of the iceberg in what's wrong with this code.  It seems to be intentionally confusing.  Here's a much simpler example of the principle going on here: http://pastebin.com/BAgQMdWU

Comment: Security through obscurity? :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go:

- A new variable named `b` is initialized with a type of `A`.
- When `b` is created, it sets the value of `b.x` to `{1, 2}`.
- `b.y` is then assigned to `b.x`, however, because they are arrays, they are now referencing the same data.
- `b.f` is called, and has `b.y` passed to it (remembering, that `b.y` and `b.x` are referencing the same data right now). Essentially, z also points to the same data during the `f` function.
- `b.f` adds 5 to the value at index 1 of the shared data, which is 2. So 2 + 5 = 7.
- First `Console.WriteLine` prints `b.x[0]` which is still 1. Then it prints `b.x[1]` which is now 7 (as above).
- Second `Console.WriteLine` prints `b.y[0]`, which is still 1 (because they share the same data). Then it prints `b.x[1]` + `b.y[1]`. They both share the same data.. and the data at index 1 is 7. 7 + 7 = 14.

You are correct about the `g` method in that the variable is local and doesn't do anything.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
b.y = b.x;
```

This line of code only copies a reference kept in `x` variable to `y` variable. So both variables reference one and the same array. So, you have only one array and two variables refering to it.

```
public void g(){...}
```

This method creates a new element, does something with it but doesn't store it anywhere, so it's lost (there are no references on it, it's ready to be garbage collected) after the method returns.

[image]

Try read [Value vs Reference](http://en.csharp-online.net/Value_vs_Reference)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!, I'm still trying to figure out how that works though (what you said about b.y and b.x) I kind of need a for dummies explanation to get it.

Comment: @KurtHDix try read [Value vs Reference](http://en.csharp-online.net/Value_vs_Reference)

Answer (score 1):

You're just confused about what's known as "identity" in programming languages. As a simplistic viewpoint, there are two categories of values in programming languages: pure values and values with identity.

Pure values can mean a few different things, but basically they adhere to the behaviour you expected, ie. each sub program gets its own "copy" of an array X that is isolated from all other subprograms given X.

Values with identity do not adhere to the above copy behaviour. An instance X is *shared* between all subprograms to which X is passed. That means all subprograms see changes made by all other subprograms.

Generally speaking, in .NET/C# documentation values with identity are called reference types. .NET's value types are a sort of "pure value" that have copy semantics. But value types can contain values with identity, and reference types can intentionally adhere to purity, so it's not necessarily so simplistic.